# Rails Devise Calling POST instead of PUT in reset password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, devise, erb, devise-recoverable

I am using devise for authentication and i have a problem in the recover password form, whose link is sent by e-mail. When I define a new password, the form is sending a POST request, instead of a PUT. It's redirecting to user/password# with 'Email can't be blank' notice.

So, edit.html.erb has method: : put, but it isn't working.
`<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>`

I'm stuck in this all day and haven't figured a way out

This is the full edit.html.erb

```
<h2>Change your password</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_password_path(resource_name),  method: :PUT) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, "New password" %><br />
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em><br />
    <% end %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm new password" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Change my password" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the generated form

```
<h2>Change your password</h2>

<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/user/password.user" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="Zf5rxkU11tVmt4i8hDpFPDL5y+/jzRQT/O/si6RnraidCN5vxofmVS1abO4nJ8iqlncZfCRr1jdLjMfxwMx45A==" />

  <input type="hidden" value="xk6EkLsyxCyvvpDyY6Ug" name="user[reset_password_token]" id="user_reset_password_token" />

  <div class="field">
    <label for="user_password">New password</label><br />
      <em>(6 characters minimum)</em><br />
    <input autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="new-password" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="user_password_confirmation">Confirm new password</label><br />
    <input autocomplete="new-password" type="password" name="user[password_confirmation]" id="user_password_confirmation" />
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Change my password" data-disable-with="Change my password" />
  </div>
</form>
```

My passwords controller

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Deals with user login and generates JWT
class User::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication
  # Render the #edit only if coming from a reset password email link
  append_before_action :assert_reset_token_passed, only: :edit
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  respond_to :json
  wrap_parameters :user

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?




  def create
   super
  end

  def edit 
    super
  end

  def update 
    super
  end

  def new 
    super
  end

end
```

My routes.rb

```
constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    scope module: 'user' do
      devise_for  :users,
                  path: '/user',
                  path_names: {
                    registration: 'signup',
                    sign_in: 'login',
                    sign_out: 'logout'
                  },
                  controllers: {
                    sessions: 'user/sessions',
                    registrations: 'user/registrations',
                    passwords: 'user/passwords'
                  }
```

Server log

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you inspect the form element, does it say method="put"?

Comment: `<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/user/password.user" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="blabla" />
` it's like this.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? Do you have `rails-ujs` properly set? It's the library that makes PUT request on HTML forms possible. https://github.com/rails/rails-ujs

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue using the Devise password reset functionality. I was adding Devise to an API Rails application (`config.api_only = true`) and apparently the `Rack::MethodOverride` middleware that is responsible for identifying the hidden method attribute and changing the request to a PUT/PATCH request was not included in the API-only middleware stack. As a result, the request made it to the main app still as a POST request.

I added the following line to `config/application.rb`, which solved the problem:

```
config.middleware.insert_after Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride
```